# Edit string using DOMDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm editing a string using Dom Document

```
$string='<iframe width="500" height="300" 
src="http://example.com/kG7ZgP81GvFeJ2ZpIaOcRQ" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" 
webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen> </iframe>';

 $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($string);
    $elem = $doc->getElementsByTagName('iframe')->item(0);
    $elem->setAttribute('width','200');
    $elem->setAttribute('height','200');
    $elem->setAttribute('style','display: inline-block;border:1px dashed');
    var_dump($elem->getAttribute('style'));
```

It is working ok. I'm getting the edited style element. But don't know **how to get whole new string with edited parts.** And is it a wrong way to edit element?

Answer (score 0):

[PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php) you should have

```
$doc->saveXML(); //XML as output
$doc->saveHTML(); //HTML as output
```

Do you have permissions to write into folder?

Comment: like i have edited the width ,i want the new string ie. ``<iframe width="200" height="200" . . . ></iframe>``

Comment: Use the above line of code for your requirement? echo $doc->saveXML();     You will get the output.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use saveHTML() like this

```
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

For further help goto this [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php)

Answer (score 0):

$doc->saveHTML() should do the trick for you. (http://www.php.net/manual/de/domdocument.savehtml.php). It returns the HTML as string.

It also has an optional parameter if you just want to get the HTML string from a childnode of your DOMDocument.

Answer (score 0):

`saveHTML` takes a parameter that defines which element will be output:

`$doc->saveHTML($elem);`